# Python for Invoicing Systems

Tags: python

I am creating an invoicing csv file using Python to track customers.  In the first year, we are installing 120 stores, 10 stores a month. In the second year, we will be installing 120 more stores, 10 stores a month.

A store pays an installation fee of $95.  The store also begins paying a monthly license the month that they are installed.  So for the 10 stores installed in January, each would pay $95 for install and 12 monthly license payments of $68.

The 10 stores installed in February would each pay the install fee of $95 and 11 monthly payments of $68, etc.

Each store is assigned an ID, starting with Store 1, which has an ID of J0001.  Each additional store ID is incremented by 1.  Therefore, at the end of year 1, the last store has an ID of J0120.

The following is my code for the first year:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

Type = 0
month = 0
year = 2016
install_fee = 95.0
license_fee = 68.0

def format_Type(Type):
return "J%04d" % (Type,)

with open('JB20.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile,
                    delimiter='\t',
                    quotechar='"',
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
writer.writerow(['Type', 'Description', 'Date', 'Status', 'Amount'])

for month in range(1, 13):
    Date = "%d-%02.d-%02.d" % (year, month, 1)
    for install in range(10):
        Type += 1
        writer.writerow([format_Type(Type), 'Install', Date, 3, install_fee])
    for Type in range(1, month * 10 + 1):
        writer.writerow([format_Type(Type), 'License', Date, 3, license_fee])
```

I am having trouble modifying the code to create additional years beyond 2016.  I can enter a different year (for example 2017), but the Store ID defaults to J0001, which is a problem because the Store IDs need to be unique for tracking.

I'd like to use the same script, but just to revise so that the ID can start at the next ID (in this case it would be J0121).

Also, the subsequent years need to also incorporate the license payments for the previous year - which I'm also having problem making the code reflect.

So for example, the first month of 2017, 10 new stores will be installed (ID J0121-J0130).  Each store will pay the install fee of $95 and the monthly license fee of $68.  However, the 120 stores from the previous year (ID J0001 - J0120) will also pay their monthly license fees.

Any ideas to revise the Python script to take into account these new factors for subsequent years would be much appreciated.